# Cannot deserialize json with Newtonsoft

Tags: c#, json

I have this json:

```
   [
      {
        "id": "89",
        "name": "Italy",
        "link": "https://int.soccerway.com/national/italy/a100/?ICID=SN_02_89",
        "iso": "IT"
      }
   ]
```

I'm trying to deserialize it with `Newtonsoft.JSON`, so I created a class model:

```
public class Country
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string link { get; set; }
    public string iso { get; set; }
}
```

and the deserialization:

```
var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Country>(content);
```

content contains the json above, anyway, this will return:

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'SWP.Models.Country' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.

Comment: The root object there is a list, so try `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Country>>(content);`

Comment: It expects a object, and you provide an array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your JSON is an array so try this:

```
var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Country>>(content);
```